# Find and Read registry key within CLR

Tags: c#, .net, registry, clr, sqlclr

I need to check the availability and also read some registry key by CLR(C#), registry keys already written by another application.
As a sample:

```
 public bool IsKeyAvailable(string KeyID)
 {
     string keyToRead = @"Software\myRoot\myApp\" + KeyID;

     using (RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyToRead, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree))
     {
        if (regKey == null)
           return false;
        return true;
     }
 }
```

Checking & reading code are working fine outside of the CLR, but within the CLR the same code doesn't working, Already signed the CLR and assembly created WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.

What could be missed for this scenario to find and read my registry keys by CLR?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code :**

Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", true);

RegistryKey masterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\yourapp\yourkey");

string value = "";

if (masterKey != null)
{
    value = masterKey.GetValue("yourvalue").ToString();
}
masterKey.Close();

Comment: Kumar My key is(and has to be) stored under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER not localMachine, however your code is not working as well

Comment: Try this code :string InstallPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MyApplication\AppPath", "Installed", null);    
if (InstallPath != null)
{
    // Do stuff
}